# What is LinkedIn crawler name?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking for **LinkedIn crawler agent name**. I have found the names of Google, Facebook and Pinterest ones but I can't find Linkedin crawler reference. I have looked on LinkedIn's developer website but can't find any reference. On Google, search results are saturated with resources to scrape content from LinkedIn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my logs, the name is `LinkedInBot/1.0`.

Here's how the bot identifies itself at the log when doing a GET.

> LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Jakarta
>   Commons-HttpClient/4.3 +http://www.linkedin.com)

Comment: Thank you. I could find it in LinkedIn documentation.